# How to change the value of my custom observable

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, observable, angularfire2

I am working on angular2 fire authentication and I have managed to make the authentication work in one way but I want to do it in a different way by creating my own custom Observable but I am not able to do that.

I have my sign in login in a service

```
constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

signIn() {
    this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
    })
    return this.af.auth; // returns an observable which is consumed in an effect
}
```

Effect which consumes this service code:

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: UserAuthService) {}

@Effect() 
login$: Observable<Action> =  this.actions$
    .ofType(UserAuthActions.ActionTypes.LOGIN)
    .switchMap(() => this.authService.signIn()) // <= switchMap takes the observable 
    // and takes care of subscribing to the observable 
    .filter(data => data !== null)
    .map((data) => {
        return {
            type: UserAuthActions.ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: {user: this.authService.getUserProfile(data)}
        }
    });
```

All good till now, But I thinking what if I do not want to expose the angularfire.auth observable instead I want to expose my custom observable `user$ = Observable.of(this.user)` which wraps around a user object, 
This user object can be fetched by subscribing to the angularfire.auth observable in the service itself. After which I can change the value of the observable `user$` and since I expose this observable the `switchMap` in the `Effect` can catch it.

```
user: any = null;
user$: Observable<any>;

constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
    // Initializing the Observable
    this.user$ = Observable.of(this.user);
    this.af.auth.subscribe(
        // change the value of user property
        data => this.user = data // this should change the value of observable
    )
}

signIn() {
    this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
    })
    return this.user$;
}
```

But doing this I can catch value once in the switchMap and that is when the constructor runs.

I am expecting it to also change when `singIn()` gets called since the `subscribe` block in constructor runs and changes the value of `this.user`.

For some reason value of `user` in `user$` is not changing although ideally it should.

I think I am missing something here about Observables can anybody help me on how to achieve it. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: this.af.auth.subscribe(
        // change the value of user property
        data => this.user = data // this should change the value of observable
    )



put this code into the signIn() and than return this.user$ in signIn()

Comment: @VinayPandya I tried your way but it isn't working moreover I think I just need to create any subscription once so I did it in constructor, your thought on that ?

Comment: constructor will run one time, and when you create object of that class. you returning this.user$ which will return simple user$ variable which is observable, that user$ will initialize first time on constructor with the value of af.auth.login observable. so put console.log() there in constructor and you will get know that what value you are getting and how many time constructor is executed.